# Listen for window events or attach objects to window

Tags: javascript, function, events, coffeescript

I have an object, which I need to control from another object.

What's a better practice and why?

Reference the object by `window.object = this` in it's constructor and then call `window.object.method()` from the other one

or

Start listening like `$(window).on 'objectEvent'` and triggering the event from the other object like `$(window).trigger('objectEvent')`?

I am currently using the second approach, but I'm wondering, whether it's the right one.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not passing/attaching the first object to the second to have a reference? It's hard to tell the good practice without context (what are these objects?).

Comment: They are modals etc. split across multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is the least bad. You want to avoid polluting the global namespace, ie: adding properties to `window`.

In the second case you are adding listeners to it, which isn't that bad if you namespace event names, but the best option would be to use an *intermediary* object and implement the **Pub/Sub** pattern, so both objects interact b/w themselves through it.